# ng2 Get Object from HttpGet Service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I am trying to get JSON data from my WebAPI and it's not working.  I always get `undefined` whenever I try to use that return object in my component.

I would like to display the student and course data on the home landing page of my website.  At the moment, my controller / api is returning the hardcoded data.

**student.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

@Injectable()
export class StudentService {
    private http: Http;            

    constructor(http: Http) {
        this.http = http;
    }

    getStudentCourse(): Observable<IStudentCourse> {
        var model: IStudentCourse;

        this.http.get('/api/student/getstudentcourse').subscribe(result => {
            model = result.json() as IStudentCourse;

            console.log(model);            

        }, error => console.log('Could not load data.'));

        console.log("model: outside of httpget: " + model);

        return Observable.of(model);        
    }
}

export interface IStudentCourse {
    refNo: string;
    student: number;
    offeringName: number;
    offeringID: string;
}
```

I can confirm that my service is returning JSON data and I can see it in Network Traffic and can see it my console.

[image]

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { StudentService, IStudentCourse } from './student.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {    

    studentCourse: IStudentCourse;
    Message: string;

    constructor(
        private _studentService: StudentService) {        
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getStudentCourse();
        console.log("fromngOnInit");
        console.log("Init: " + this.studentCourse.offeringName);
    }

    getStudentCourse() {        
        this._studentService.getStudentCourse().subscribe(
            item => this.studentCourse = Object.assign({}, item),
            error => this.Message = <any>error);
    }
}
```

You can see in my screenshot that, `studentCourse` is always null in `ngOnInit` and I couldn't manage to bind it.

Could you please help me with this error?  Thanks.

**Updated:** [plnkr Link](https://embed.plnkr.co/yvgkJzXrMULIeiZO4q2W/)

I prefer to put this HttpGet service in the separate service file because I need to use it in other components too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see `plunker` : [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/EcBCpHORgJNj3vwfIv4u)

in your template use `?`:

```
<h2>Hello {{studentCourse?.student}}</h2>
```

don't subscribe in the service , you can do this:

```
 getStudentCourse(): Observable<IStudentCourse> {
        let model: IStudentCourse;

        return this.http.get('/api/student/getstudentcourse').map(result => {
            model = result.json() as IStudentCourse;
            return model;
        }).catch( error => console.log('Could not load data.'));

    }
```

Comment: why can't he subscribe twice ?

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work.  It shows an syntax error.  I have put the Plnkr link as the mock.  Could you help please?

Comment: @TTCG see the update I edit it your plunker it works now

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a n Observable of your model which is empty at that time. It is async.

try this:

```
getStudentCourse(): Observable<IStudentCourse>: {
    return this.http.get('/api/student/getstudentcourse')
        .map(result => result.json() as IStudentCourse)        
        .catch(() => throw 'Could not load data.');

}
```

See [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/m8YvbuzEfQqH2NKht8jU?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't still work.  It shows syntax error.  I have put the Plnkr link as the mock.  Could you help please?

Comment: If I hardcode studentCourse data (without HttpCall), it works.  As you said, the data is loaded only after the page is fully loaded.  But I couldn't manage to load the data only before the page Load.

Comment: Fantastic, It works now.  I accepted the earliest answer as the correct one.  I appreciate your help and can learn different styles of binding data.

Comment: Thanks, notice the message is set when an error occurs. This does't work in the other examples...

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `BehaviorSubject` for this task and in your Http Subscription emit a new value for the Subject.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';


@Injectable()
export class StudentService {
    private studentCourse: BehaviorSubject<IStudentCourse> = new BehaviorSubject<IStudentCourse>(null);

    public get studentCourse$() { 
        return this.studentCourse.asObservable();
    }

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getStudentCourse() {
       this.http.get('https://58cff77fe1a0d412002e446d.mockapi.io/api/student/getstudentcourse/2').map(response => {
         return response.json() as IStudentCourse;
      }).subscribe(course => {
         this.studentCourse.next(course);
      });
    }
}

export interface IStudentCourse {
  id: string,
  refNo: string;
  student: string;
}
```

And in your `template` use Angular `async` Pipe to auto subscribe to the Observable holding the Data.

[Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/4pJRjM7NqXGzrC7nbFfL/)

Comment: Your one works too.  I accepted the earliest answer as the correct one.  Thanks for your help and can learn about 'BehaviorSubject' too.