# get value from [object object] in Angular4

Tags: json, angular, typescript

This is the code from my last question:

```
getUserRole() {
  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.getToken()}`);
  console.log(this.getToken());
  const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});

  return this.http.get(`${this.baseURL + this.loginApiRoot}/GetUserRoles`,options).pipe(map(res => res.json()))
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.userRole = JSON.stringify(data);
      if (this.userRole === 'parent') {
        this.logout();
      } else if (this.userRole === 'school') {
        this.isUser = true;
        this.isAdmin = false;
        this.cookieService.set('isSchool', '1');
      } else if (this.userRole === 'admin') {
        this.isUser = false;
        this.isAdmin = true;
        this.cookieService.set('isAdmin', '1');
      }
    });
}
```

But when I am trying to access `userRole` after calling this function, I get `userRole undefined`, maybe due to it gets returned before `.subscribe` gets hit.

As a result I get this as `undefined`:

```
var result = this.getUserRole(token);
console.log('Call from login ' + result);
```

So, I have changed the approach to be something like this:

```
getUserRole(roletoken: string) {
  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${roletoken}`);
  const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});
  var result = this.http.get(`${this.baseURL + this.loginApiRoot}/GetUserRoles`, options).pipe(map(res => res.json()));
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}
```

But here I am getting `result` as `[object object]`.

May I know which approach should I go with to immediately get `userRole` assigned by either method.

In second method I am not able to convert `[object object]` into the value.

The data I receive from API is something like this:

```
["school"]
```

This is the calling:

```
this.getUserRole(token);
console.log('Call from login ' + this.userRole);
```

This is inside `getUserRole` function:

```
var result = this.http.get(`${this.baseURL + this.loginApiRoot}/GetUserRoles`, options).subscribe(data => {
  this.userRole = JSON.stringify(data);
  console.log(data);
});
```

And this is the sequence of console I am getting:

> Call from login undefined
>
> Response {_body: "["school"]", status: 200, ok: true, statusText:
>   "OK", headers: Headers, …}

So, even trying the code with subscribe, the assignment of `userRole` is getting latter by calling from login.

Comment: Are you using `Http` or `HttpClient`?

Comment: I am using Http

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getUserRole` returns an `Observable`. As you've seen you need to `subscribe` to it to make the HTTP call and receive the data. Since you're using the legacy `Http` class, instead of `HttpClient`, you need to convert the response to the actual JSON data. The code below should work:

```js
getUserRole(roletoken: string) {
  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${roletoken}`);
  const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});
  return this.http.get(`${this.baseURL + this.loginApiRoot}/GetUserRoles`, options).pipe(map(response => response.json()));
}
```

It's important to understand the asynchronous nature of `Observables`, and HTTP requests. `this.userRole` is only set after the request has completed. Thus, if you want to do something with `this.userRole` and want to be certain it has a value, you should use it inside of the subscribe function:

```js
this.getUserRole(token).subscribe(userRole => { 
  this.userRole = userRole;
  console.log('Call from login ' + this.userRole);
});
```

Comment: it is saying undefined

Comment: What is saying `undefined` when and where? How do you expect to use the value of `getUserRole`?

Comment: Note that any usage of `this.userRole` outside of the function passed to `subscribe` _could_ result in `undefined`. This is due to the asynchronous nature of HTTP calls. The right answer really depends on how you want to use `this.userRole`.

Comment: userRole is globally declares for the export class, the getUserRole is simply storing role in this variable and login function is accessing the same. And I did what you exactly suggested.

Comment: I understand `this.userRole` refers to a property on the class. Could you provide the code that uses this property?

Comment: this.getUserRole(token).subscribe(userRole => this.userRole = userRole);
                    console.log('Call from login ' + this.userRole); I am using your code to get it done. Now I am very much confused.

Comment: I've modified my answer. You should understand that due to the asynchronous nature of `Observables`, `console.log(this.userRole);` on the line after `subscribe` will result in `undefined`. Please read documentation to understand `Observables` better. Otherwise you'll keep running into problems with this.

Comment: Yes I understand it is async, but the fact is I have to use it as quick as it is assigned.

Comment: I still have to try, but conceptually you are absolutely right, I am going through the proper documentation now.

Answer (score 0):

what I would have done would be,
if your rest api send you a json

```
    userRole: UserRole // here you set the type of userRole as UserRole that you defined earlier or in an other file
    getUserRole() {
  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.getToken()}`);
  console.log(this.getToken());
  const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});
  return this.http.get<UserRole>(`${this.baseURL + this.loginApiRoot}/GetUserRoles`,options)
  .subscribe(data => {
  this.userRole = data;
    if (this.userRole === 'parent') {
      this.logout();
  } else if (this.userRole === 'school') {
    this.isUser = true;
    this.isAdmin = false;
    this.cookieService.set('isSchool', '1');
  } else if (this.userRole === 'admin') {
    this.isUser = false;
    this.isAdmin = true;
    this.cookieService.set('isAdmin', '1');
  }
  });
```

}

if your api send you a list of json I would do, (it can be a list of a one json something like [{name: 'name', first_name:'first_name'}])

```
    userRole: UserRole // here you set the type of userRole as UserRole that you defined earlier or in an other file
    getUserRole() {
  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.getToken()}`);
  console.log(this.getToken());
  const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});
  return this.http.get<UserRole[]>(`${this.baseURL + this.loginApiRoot}/GetUserRoles`,options)
  .subscribe(data => {
  this.userRole = data[0];   // of course here if you want them all you will make a loop and use this.userRoles set as userRoles: UserRole[]
    if (this.userRole === 'parent') {
      this.logout();
  } else if (this.userRole === 'school') {
    this.isUser = true;
    this.isAdmin = false;
    this.cookieService.set('isSchool', '1');
  } else if (this.userRole === 'admin') {
    this.isUser = false;
    this.isAdmin = true;
    this.cookieService.set('isAdmin', '1');
  }
  });
```

}

it seems like your api don't give you a json if it really give you something like 
['school']
and not something like [{role: 'school'}]
I would try

```
    getUserRole() {
  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.getToken()}`);
  console.log(this.getToken());
  const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});
  return this.http.get(`${this.baseURL + this.loginApiRoot}/GetUserRoles`,options).pipe(map(res => res.json()))
  .subscribe(data => {
  this.userRole = JSON.stringify(data[0]);  // data is a list you take the first element 
    if (this.userRole === 'parent') {
      this.logout();
  } else if (this.userRole === 'school') {
    // same
```

}

or

```
    getUserRole() {
  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.getToken()}`);
  console.log(this.getToken());
  const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});
  return this.http.get(`${this.baseURL + this.loginApiRoot}/GetUserRoles`,options).pipe(map(res => res.json()))
  .subscribe(data => {
  this.userRole = JSON.stringify(data);  // data is a list you take the first element 
    if (this.userRole[0] === 'parent') {
      this.logout();
  } else if (this.userRole[0] === 'school') {
    // same but you take the first element of the list
```

}

I am not sure of the last 2 as I used to get json response from my apis but that's what I would check in a first time and see what I get

don't forget you can debug and see the value of your variable at each step using a browser debugger like you have in chrome just set a breakpoints at the beginning of your function and follow it ;)

Comment: Yeah I know I am getting result from API as object and NOT json and achieved the same by getting the value. But question is not this. The point is I will get my variable assigned just after using it from the calling method. Pl read my comments for Sajeetharan

Comment: oh so you mean the issue is this.userRole is defined after you you would like to use it ? if so how do you call this function in an other ts file or in a html file ?

Comment: if you are using Http did you check that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42905990/ng2-get-object-from-httpget-service it seems like you should map but not subscribe, in your function definition